# Type for parallel or sequential collection in scala

Tags: scala, types, parallel-processing

I have the following value:

```
val a = (1 to 10).toVector
```

And want to define the following function:

```
def sum1(a: ParOrSeqVector) = a.map(_+1)
```

That can deal with sequential or parallel Vector,

```
sum1(a)
sum1(a.par)
```

How can I do this?

The extends from [Scala API ParVector](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/parallel/immutable/ParVector.html) didn't give me any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 methods for this

1) Declare a function that accepts a parameter of type GenSeq

```
val a: Vector[Int] = (1 to 10).toVector
val a1: ParVector[Int] = ParVector.range(0, 10)

def sum2(a: GenSeq[Int]) = a.map(_+1)

sum2(a)
sum2(a1)
```

2) Accept a function that accepts a parameter Any and then do pattern matching on it.

```
val a: Vector[Int] = (1 to 10).toVector
val a1: ParVector[Int] = ParVector.range(0, 10)

def sum1(a: Any) =
{
  a match {
    case x :Vector[Int] =>  x.map(_+1)
    case y :ParVector[Int] => y.map(_+1)
  }
}

sum1(a)
sum1(a1)
```

Both the cases will give you output in the format

```
sum2: sum2[](val a: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int]) => scala.collection.GenSeq[Int]

res2: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
res3: scala.collection.GenSeq[Int] = ParVector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Hope this clarifies your question. Please feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem, now I see that ParVector extends ParSeq, and ParSeq extends GenSeq.